# invoking keypress event without actually pressing key in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

hi i want spacebar to be fired in javascript without pressing spacebar in textbox,i tried this code please help me to solve this

```
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            var getOldValue = jQuery("#<%=txtCompany.ClientID%>");
                var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
                e.which = 32; //key code
                jQuery("#<%=txtCompany.ClientID%>").trigger(e);

        });
    </script>
```

and aspx page is

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtCompany"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: You are asking question for Javascript and using code for JQuery, it's misleading to responder.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the server side markup on a client side script. This cannot work. Instead, ASP will create an HTML input box with id equal txtCompany. So lets use that.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var inputBox = jQuery("#txtCompany"), 
        getOldValue = inputBox.val(),
        e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
    e.which = 32; //key code
    inputBox.trigger(e);
});
```

I haven't done the event triggering in the way that you are with the jQuery.Event() but if that is valid code, then this should solve your problem.

Comment: but i need to use asp control(textbox) only..we cant do anything?

Comment: The asp control becomes HTML. In the page HTML, what does that asp control become? `<input type="text" id="txtCompany" />`? If so, try my method. . If not, use your browsers debugger to inspect it.

Answer (score 0):

u can use[initKeyEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.initKeyEvent) and in jquery

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
e.which = 50; //key code
$("#some_element").trigger(e);
```

and in vanilla javascript, this is how it works:

```
// Create the event
var evt = document.createEvent( 'KeyboardEvent' );

// Init the options
event.initKeyEvent(
         "keypress",        //  the kind of event
          true,             //  boolean "can it bubble?"
          true,             //  boolean "can it be cancelled?"
          null,             //  specifies the view context (usually window or null)
          false,            //  boolean "Ctrl key?"
          false,            //  boolean "Alt key?"
          false,            //  Boolean "Shift key?"
          false,            //  Boolean "Meta key?"
           9,               //  the keyCode
           0);              //  the charCode

// Dispatch the event on the element
el.dispatchEvent( evt );
```

Comment: can you explain how to generate space by using spacebar key code in a textbox?